# SfDataPager stops showing source collection if I manipulate it. (Source collection filled asynchronously)

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming, reactiveui, syncfusion

XAML of data pager and data grid which shows collection:

```
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataPager,Path=PagedSource}" 
                               ColumnSizer="Auto"/>
        <syncfusion:SfDataPager x:Name="dataPager"
                                Source="{Binding Orders,IsAsync=True}"
                                PageSize="30"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I have search box when I write something in search box my collection is being filtered relating to the text I write in search box.

```
    SourceList<Order> ordersList;

    public JournalViewModel(NorthwindContext northwindContext)
    {
        ordersList = new SourceList<Order>();

        //Filling of Orders collection
        ordersList.Connect().
            ObserveOnDispatcher().
            Bind(out _ordersList).
            Subscribe();

        //When I write something in the search box this code runs
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm).
            Subscribe(newSearchTerm =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newSearchTerm))
                {
                    //Logic of reloading collection
                }
                else
                {
                    //Logic of filtering collection
                }
            });
      }

      //Source property of Text property of search box
      public string SearchTerm
      {
          get { return _searchTerm; }
          set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChan ged(ref _searchTerm, value); }
      }

      ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Order> _ordersList;
      public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Order> Orders => _ordersList;
```

So every time my collection is manipulated, data pager stops to show my collection. Why does this happening and how to make data pager show filtered collection?

May be useful: Initially I had a problem with showing collection itself because my collection is filled through reactive request. I have solved this problem by setting IsAsync property of binding to true.

**EDIT** 16.03.2020: For example if I need to clear collection which keep 830 items and than fill it with new items I use `Clear` and `AddRange` methods from DynamicData, SfDataPager do not show filtered collection. But if I use `foreach` construction:

```
            foreach (var order in currentList)
                ordersList.Remove(order);

            foreach (var order in newList)
                ordersList.Add(order);
```

Data pager shows me filtered collection. Why does this occur?

Comment: We have checked the reported issue with SfDataPager, but unfortunately, we could not able to replicate the reported issue. It's working fine from our end. We have tested with Syncfusion version 17.4.0.46. Please check [this sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SearchPanelWithdatapager1132445725) and revert us if you still facing the same issue? If not, please modify the sample based on your scenario. It will be helpful for us to check on it and provide you with the solution at the earliest.

Comment: Hello @SusmithaSundar thanks for your reply. I have noticed that your methods in sample executing synchronously. Whileas my collection is being updated asynchronously.
Note: For example if I delete one record from collection through asynchronously Task SfDataGrid shows changes. But if I delete for example range of records SfDataGrid stops to show collection. Maybe this info will be useful

Comment: Hi,  

We have checked the sample by loading the data asynchronously. And try to delete the rows by single row and multiple rows. Its works fine as expected. Please refer to the below video link, 

Video link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/RowDeleting950084153 

 

Can you please share the code snippet for deleting the rows? It will be helpful for us to check on it and provide you the solution at the earliest.

Comment: Hi @MohanramAnbukkarasu. I have checked async operations everything works fine. There is no problem in SfDataPager. But I am using another framework and maybe problem is that they can not collaborate. I am using ReactiveUI. Please look [this sample](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjgMnf2IN94_lyljzqcEyygN_ma7?e=oy9glg). Maybe you have an explanation why it is happening?